# Automatically animate a slider with a button

Tags: javascript, html, input, slider, jquery-animate

I have a slider (that I found on stackoverflow) that changes automatically images:

```html
<input id="valR" type="range" min="1" max="48" value="0" step="1" oninput="showVal(this.value)" onchange="showVal(this.value)" />
    <span id="range">0</span>
    <img id="img">

<script>

    var val = document.getElementById("valR").value;
        document.getElementById("range").innerHTML=val;
        document.getElementById("img").src ="Precipitation/06z/HRDPS-Precipitation_Surface.06z.f001.jpg";
        function showVal(newVal){
          document.getElementById("range").innerHTML=newVal;
            if(newVal >= 1 && newVal < 2)
            document.getElementById("img").src = "Precipitation/06z/HRDPS-Precipitation_Surface.06z.f001.jpg";
            else if(newVal >= 2 && newVal < 3)
            document.getElementById("img").src = "Precipitation/06z/HRDPS-Precipitation_Surface.06z.f002.jpg";
<!--etc-->
}
</script>
```

But I would like an "Animate" toggle button that could automatically move the slider when clicked (and thus change the images)

Thank you so much for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updated

Just add the button with onclick event and manipulate the object.

```js
let val = document.getElementById("valR").value;
document.getElementById("range").innerHTML = val;
document.getElementById("img").src = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/879/879761.png";

function showVal(newVal){
  document.getElementById("range").innerHTML=newVal;
  if(newVal <= 10) document.getElementById("img").src = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/879/879761.png";
  else if(newVal <= 20) document.getElementById("img").src = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/3712/3712363.png";
  else document.getElementById("img").src = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/744/744922.png";
 // Note that I change the if condition, so you could see the difference of the image between some ranged value
}

document.getElementById("inc").onclick = function(){
    val = parseInt(document.getElementById("range").innerHTML) + 1;
    (val > 48) ? val = 48 : val
    document.getElementById("range").innerHTML=val;
    document.getElementById("valR").value = val;
    showVal(val);
};

document.getElementById("dec").onclick = function(){
    val = parseInt(document.getElementById("range").innerHTML) - 1;
    (val < 0) ? val = 0 : val
    document.getElementById("range").innerHTML=val;
    document.getElementById("valR").value = val;
    showVal(val);
};
```

```css
button{
  margin-top:15px;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<input id="valR" type="range" min="1" max="48" value="0" step="1" oninput="showVal(this.value)" onchange="showVal(this.value)" />
<span id="range">0</span>
<img id="img">
<button id="inc">Increment</button>
<button id="dec">Decrement</button>
```

Comment: The number is changing but not the image nor the slider state.
Too, it is kinda glitchy: if I slide the slider to let say 5 and click on increment, it goes to -1 (which it shouldn't) and the limit is not capped at 48.

Either way, Thank you for the time :)

Comment: hello @TechEdd_YT I already update the answer, pardon me for the "glitchy things" and I hope this is just the way you wanted. I'll appreciate if you do click the correct answer and the upvote. Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the update!
There is still a small glitch: the "grey round circle thing" is not moving with the buttons if you understand what I mean. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Yup i don't understand what you mean, is the button needs to move with the slider?

Comment: Sorry, my comment wasn't clear. When I click on Increment (for ex.) the grey circle don't move right. It stays at the same place. And when I click Dec, the value goes to -1... etc. 
Ty

Comment: @TechEdd_YT I already updated my code again as requested, please click the upvote and mark the answer as correct.